# how to display content using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I want to preview content,when i click on the anchor tag,

```
                    var profiledemo = profiles.split(",");
                    for (var pd = 0; pd < profiledemo.length; pd++) {
                        var mydiv = document.getElementById("Profile");
                        var aTag = document.createElement('a');
                        aTag.setAttribute('href');
                        aTag.innerHTML = profiledemo[pd];
                        mydiv.appendChild(aTag);                               
                        aTag.onclick = function () {
                            alert("profiles anchor tag called");

                        }
                    }
```

I am able to display multiple docs and for those docs i put anchor tag using above,now I want,when user click on the particular tag I have to display that doc content  which is in database.

Comment: you can use ajax. You can create a GET request in Ajax containing the document name and then return the content from the servr which you can display in another div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding events in plain javascript is not much convenient, cause IE and other browsers offer different API, so you'll have to check for browser type and maintain cross-browser compatibility.
You'd better use jQuery.

```
$(aTag).click(function() { alert("..."); });
```

By the way is it necessary to construct the anchor programmatically? I'd recommend to embed html anchor and display when necessary.